# Is Collection.stream().filter().forEach() inefficient compared to a standard for each loop?

Tags: java, performance, java8

IntelliJ IDEA recommended to me just now to replace the following for-each loop with a Java 8 "forEach" call:

```
    for (Object o : objects) {
        if (o instanceof SomeObject) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
```

The recommended call would like like this:

```
objects.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof SomeObject).forEach(o -> doSomething());
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding how the underlying functionality of Stream works, it seems to me like using stream is an O(2n) operation as opposed to an O(n) operation for the standard for-each loop.

Comment: Why do you think it's O^2? In fact, streams were invented specifically to (a) allow nicer syntax and (b) *not* introduce extra overhead. (In fact, they often *reduce* overhead via lazy evaluation.)

Comment: Just based on the syntax, it looks like it's first iterating to filter and then iterating over the filtered objects a second time to run my code.

Comment: Even if it did that that would still be O(2*N), which is O(N), i.e. linear and not quadratic. But actually the iterations are interleaved with each other, and both may terminate early if the result is already known - that's the beauty of streams. It's definitely worth spending 15 minutes to read up on the streams in Java 8; as Venkat Subramaniam writes, ''Lambda expressions are the gateway drug to Java 8, but Streams are the real addiction.''

Comment: Sorry, 2n is what I meant - not n^2.

Comment: Besides: your loop is an antipattern ;)

Comment: @ThomasJunk Can you explain how it's an antipattern? I'm not familiar with this one.

Comment: @agent154 I think it's the whole list of objects and then using `instanceof` but I'm assuming  it's  just an example anyway

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Java streams do not iterate through your collection once for each statement, despite what the syntax implies. It applies the entire chain to each element, one element at a time.

In your case, the stream would operate exactly like the loop. Take an element, check it against your predicate, and then apply your operation, then move on to the next element.